# Java Stream close method ambiguous behaviour

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

Given this Java class:

```
class MyClass {
    private int value;

    public MyClass(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value: " + value;
    }
}
```

And given this Java code:

```
Consumer<MyClass> cons = mc -> mc.setValue(mc.getValue() * mc.getValue());

List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyClass(1));
list.add(new MyClass(2));
list.add(new MyClass(3));

System.out.println(list);
```

I got this output: [Value: 1, Value: 2, Value: 3]

When I ran this code:

```
list.stream().peek(cons).close();   //1
System.out.println(list);
```

I expected as output [Value: 1, Value: 4, Value: 9], but instead I got [Value: 1, Value: 2, Value: 3],
so the elements in the list had not been modified.

But when I ran this:

```
list.stream().forEach(cons);        //2
```

and this:

```
list.stream().peek(cons).count();   //3
```

I got the output that I expected ([Value: 1, Value: 4, Value: 9]) both times

Why didn't line //1 give me this output? I suppose that is because close(): how does this method work?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Because close() is not a terminal operation. It doesn't consume the stream. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#close--

Comment: @JBNizet I wasn't aware of the close listener thing at all. Is `close()` guaranteed to be called after terminal operations?

Comment: @daniu https://stackoverflow.com/a/50875167/1059372

Comment: @daniu [Why doesn't Java close() stream after a terminal operation is issued?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28813637/2711488)…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`close`, will be triggered no matter if there is a terminal operation or not ; if it is used in a `try with resource` or `close` is called upon the stream itself; but either way it's not a terminal operation. So it's neither an `intermediate` one or a `terminal` one - it's somehow special.

```
    Stream<Integer> s2 = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
    s2.onClose(() -> System.out.println("Closing 2"));
    s2.close(); // will print Closing 2
```

But also see this:

```
    try (Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(1, 2, 3)) {
        s.onClose(() -> System.out.println("Closing"));
        s.filter(x -> x > 1)
         .peek(x -> System.out.println("foud one"));
    }
```

Run this and see for yourself that in the second example `peek` is not triggered, but `close` is.

So to answer your question, the correct verbiage would be that : `close` is not a terminal operation, thus your stream pipeline is not executed.

Comment: Hmm--hmm... but it might be called several times if called explicitly and then by a `try-with-resource` or terminal operation, right? So you have to take care the `Runnable`s you register have idempotent behavior.

Comment: @daniu - no, the terminal operation will *not* trigger the `close`; then no matter how many times you call close - the `Runnable` will be triggered just once - there is a flag internally that sort of is like *was close already called*

Comment: `close` is not a terminal operation, but that’s missing the point. Even if it was a terminal operation, it didn’t imply that the action passed to `peek` gets executed, as `peek` is supposed to debug the processing of the elements and `close` doesn’t need to process any elements. Look at the OP’s third example, `list.stream().peek(cons).count();`. It happens to process all elements in Java 8, but starting with Java 9, it will deliver the answer without processing any elements, hence, not execute the action passed to `peek`. So being a terminal operation does not imply executing that action…

Comment: @Holger right, this was just to prove the point that the terminal operation gets executed, but I totally agree, I should have relied on the side effect of the terminal operation itself when explaining. As usual, very much appreciated

Comment: Note that `onClose` is an intermediate operation that should be used like all other intermediate operations, i.e. you should use the result of the call: `s2 = s2.onClose(() -> System.out.println("Closing 2"))` or chain the subsequent operation directly to it, like `s2.onClose(() -> System.out.println("Closing 2")).close();` or `try (Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).onClose(() -> System.out.println("Closing")) { … }`. Do not rely on `onClose` changing the state of the old stream instance.

Answer (score 0):

`peek` is an intermediate operation and does not trigger the stream processing pipeline unless you have a terminal operator in it. So the statement,

```
list.stream().peek(cons).close();
```

does not have a terminal operation, and the stream pipeline is not triggered at all, hence the consumer is not executed, leading to the result you observe. The list remains unmodified. However this is not due to the `close` method in streams.

In both the other instances,

```
list.stream().forEach(cons);        
list.stream().peek(cons).count();
```

You have terminal operations `forEach` and `count`, hence the consumer is executed leading to the modification of the original list.