# How do I avoid using try-with-resources or close() in this example?

Tags: java, java-stream, lazy-evaluation, try-with-resources, resource-leak

I am trying to stream data from the internet using [`java.util.stream.Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html). I have an implementation that works. Here is it below.

```java
final URL url =
   new
      URI
      (
         "INSERT YOUR HYPERLINK HERE. Mine is this 5.2 gb file --> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us.csv"
      )
      .toURL()
      ;

try
(
   final InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
   final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
   final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
)
{
   final Stream<String> lines = bufferedReader.lines();
   //do what you want with the stream here.    
}
catch (final Exception exception)
{
   throw new RuntimeException(exception);
}
```

Because it is a `Stream`, the execution is lazy. It only fetches the minimum necessary from the upstream source (the internet). This is ideal because I can short-circuit and save myself from downloading more from the internet than needed.

The problem though is all of the try-with-resources. I am not opposed to writing them, but I plan to use this implementation as part of a team. So, a lot of people would be using it. To avoid errors, I want to remove at least one particular tripping hazard -- the need for a try-with-resources.

I would like to avoid running into memory/resouce issues because someone forgot to do a try-with-resources. Or a `close()` method, since that would be the same problem, but even easier to forget.

How would you all work around this problem?

---

Here is my progress thus far.

I saw this talk by Venkat Subremaniam, in which he described the "Execute-Around Method Pattern" --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTuwi--LFsM&t=7920s

Long story short, the "Execute Around Method Pattern" allows you to dodge the concern for resource misutilization by simply not letting your callers have the resource. Instead, you let the caller pass in a [`java.util.function.Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html) whose parameterize type is the resource you are not letting them have, and then simply let them specify in the `Consumer` the functions they would have called with the resource, if you would have let them have one.

On the one hand, this pattern works ***perfectly*** for my problem. The `Stream` does all the things the `Consumer` tells it to, and then it closes itself once the `Consumer` completes. Here is a complete, runnable implementation that I made.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StreamDataFromTheInternet
{
   public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      StreamDataFromTheInternet
         .executeAroundMethodPattern
         (
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us.csv" //THIS IS A 5 GIGABYTE FILE
            ,
            lines ->
               lines
                  .filter(line -> line.length() > 20) //filter down to lines that are >20 characters
                  .limit(10)                          //of those lines, only grab the first 10
                  .forEach(System.out::println)       //print them out to console
         )
         ;
      //Doing it this way allowed us to avoid downloading the entire 5GB file.
      //Instead, we downloaded only a couple of kb.
      //Basically, we only downloaded as many lines as we needed to in order
      //to complete the Stream.
   }

   private static void executeAroundMethodPattern(final String hyperlink, Consumer<Stream<String>> functionToExecute) throws Exception
   {
      final URL url =
         new
            URI
            (
               hyperlink
            )
            .toURL()
            ;
   
      try
      (
         final InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
         final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
         final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
      )
      {
         final Stream<String> lines = bufferedReader.lines();
         functionToExecute.accept(lines);
      }
      catch (final Exception exception)
      {
         throw new RuntimeException(exception);
      }
   }
}
```

So, this looks like exactly what I am looking for... assuming that I am only doing code that involves side-effects.

But really, most instances of `Stream` are supposed to *produce* a value. Doing a side-effect is really the secondary use-case of a `Stream`. I want to provide the primary use-case, but with all the safety that I am giving the secondary use-case.

I'll spare you the long rabbit hole and basically boil it down to saying -- returning a value is easy enough, but I couldn't find a way to stop the user from just returning the `Stream` itself, nullifying the entire point of what I am trying to do here.

Any ideas of how to work around it?

**EDIT** - I see that I was unclear with the last paragraph. Apologies for that, I was certainly not descriptive enough.

Yes, I obviously could swap my `Consumer` for a `Function`, but a problem very quickly arises with only a little testing --- what happens if the user returns the `Stream` itself?

Long story short, the `Stream` will blow up in their face if it attempts to fetch any more data from the internet ***because the try-with-resources block closed the readers***. You cannot fetch data from a reader that is closed, and if you attempt to do so, you will get an Exception.

So, no. Simply swapping a `Consumer` for a `Function` will not solve my problem here. Ultimately, all it does is swap one problem for another. Instead of a resource leak, we now have a `Stream` that could blow up in your face for using it in an otherwise innocent way. Yes, code reviews and the like could prevent this, but if I could depend on code reviews from solving this problem, I would not have asked it in the first place. The team I am intending this code to be used for simply contains too many juniors producing so much code, that the reviewers are overburdened. I cannot depend on reviews, and I would rather not release the feature than try to depend on reviews.

I want to create a guard rail, not a warning sign. And the suggested solution to simply return an unusable stream is like having a guard rail with a gap in the middle of it -- it looks like it protects you unless you happen to crash near the gap. More specifically, it is like having a gap in our guard rail, and a warning sign warning you about he gap in the guard rail lol. In that respect, it is the worst of both worlds.

And finally, let me say that I want a durable guard rail, or no road. If what I ask is impossible, and you can demonstrate that, by all means, I don't need to have the road. This function I am providing is a convenience to help people write better code. It enables a safe abstraction. But an abstraction is only as good as it is airtight. The second it starts to leak (warning sign vs guard rail), it's usefulness drops exponentially. I am not saying that I need an abstraction that can model my entire context, I just need it to model a single use-case, and accomplish that with existing semantics of a `Stream`. If that cannot be maintained, then I would rather abandon the abstraction (`Stream`) entirely.

Comment: I feel like StackOverflow is a good place for this question. But if it would make more sense on CodeReview, I can move it there. Please lmk.

Comment: why not add a check to check that the generic value to return is not an instance of a stream, and if it is throw an invalid argument exception? Though I was hoping there was some way to specify that a generic object should _not_ be a type of object, doesnt seem possible.

Comment: `Stream` is `Autocloseable`, so put `final Stream<String> lines = bufferedReader.lines();` in the `try` too. Then a returned `Stream` will be unusable.

Comment: "I couldn't find a way to stop the user from just returning the Stream itself, nullifying the entire point of what I am trying to do here": I do not understand. Consumers don't return anything. Please clarify.

Comment: So you seem to be saying the `executeAroundMethodPattern ` would be ideal if it could return a value. Couldn’t we produce a value indirectly? Couldn’t the author of the `Consumer` declare a modifiable collection like an `ArrayList` before the call to `executeAroundMethodPattern`, then change the `.forEach(System.out::println)` line to `.forEach(myList::add)`? (I’ve not yet tried this. Just a guess.)

Comment: If you want it to return a value, just change `Consumer<T>` to `Function<T,V>` where `V` is the return type, and `functionToExecute.accept(lines)` to `return functionToExecute.accept(lines)`. Otherwise I still have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: ***why not add a check*** -- @BIBOOunit1998X that is a paper wall. I am not trying to avoid returning the `Stream` because a `Stream` is bad, I want to avoid returniing the `Stream` so that the resources do not remain in use. If I can stop using the resource and still return a `Stream`, then that should be a valid use case of my API.

Comment: ***`Stream` is `AutoCloseable`*** -- @tgdavies Yes, but that is hardly any better. If we are returning unusable instances of `Stream`, then I have readded a similar risk that I have been trying to avoid for this API. I am swapping out a resource leak for the resource equivalent of a null-check.

Comment: ***just change `Consumer<T>` to `Function<T,V>`*** -- @user207421 This is what the answer suggests, and it is the worst of both worlds. If I were to do what you say, then what happens if the user decides to return the `Stream` itself? And that would be very easy to do accidentally -- simply remove a terminal operation. Well, if the `Stream` attempts to grab anymore bytes from upstream, it will throw an Exception because we closed the readers. I would sooner abandon the ability to return a value than attempt that.

Comment: @BasilBourque You are essentially saying, have my method continue to be `void`, but offer that as a suggestion to the user in case they want to return something? So far, that is the closest thing to an answer I have gotten. If you make that as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: Another idea is to look at the practical uses the calling programmer is likely to have: producing a subset after filtering, sorting, and limiting. You could build a method that takes a predicate for filtering, a comparator for sorting, and a number for the limit. The method returns a collection. No stream is ever seen by the calling programmers. The stream is an internal implementation detail.

Comment: @BasilBourque True. In that respect, would it make sense to try subclassing the Stream itself? It feels like I could accomplish what you describe and more, all while my end user is none the wiser.

Comment: Yet another approach would be to cache the 5 gigs of data in a local H2 database, and give your juniors read-only access via JDBC or a *Repository* interface you devise. No stream and no external file exposed to the juniors.

Comment: Just let them return the closed stream. The code that uses it won't work, so the problem will fix itself in development. Document and hand-wave.

Comment: @user207421 I am not saying that I fear this going to PROD. I am saying that I don't want the wasted iterations in the first place. If this is going to contribute to wasted iterations, I would sooner just do the `Consumer` and call it a day.

Comment: @BasilBourque So to be clear, the 5gb is purely a demo example that I used to make a point. The actual data set I am referring to is in the hundreds of terabytes. Not to say that the juniors are streaming hundreds of terabytes. More so that there are hundreds of terabytes worth of multi-gb files. I can't put them all into cache, and it's unknown ahead of time which one is needed.

Comment: So I am once again having difficulty discovering what your problem actually is. What for example does 'wasted iterations' mean?

Comment: I've deleted my answer since that's apparently not what you're looking for. What you seem to want is not possible or is possible but with a significant amount of unnecessary effort. Regardless, I think you're worrying about a non-issue. Just close the stream and let developers run into the exception (which they shouldn't if they read the documentation).

Comment: "_I am not saying that I need an abstraction that can model my entire context, I just need it to model a single use-case_" -- If your "single use-case" is simple, like a filter, then do as Basil suggests and only let the user see the individual elements via a `Predicate` or whatever without ever seeing the stream itself.

Comment: "_And finally, let me say that I want a durable guard rail, or no road_" -- I'd argue that an execute-around method that accepts a `Function` and guarantees the `Stream` is closed before it returns is a _good_ solution, even if it doesn't actively prevent returning the stream itself. The method would still prevent what I suspect _should_ be your primary concern: An _open_ stream that exists beyond the appropriate context and/or consumes more data than necessary. Based on your edit, giving your team unmanaged access to the stream is the worse option. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: @user207421 When I say iteration, I am talking about a single iteration in the code, build, deploy, test cycle. So, a solution that is prone to making people go for more iterations due to simple mistakes like using a closed Stream is an example of a wasted iteration. A good way to not waste the full iteration, and have it fail upon build. Then, you have saved much more time. That is an example of wasting much less time. If it helps, I have added a sizable edit that goes into detail about some of the things that I am looking for.

Comment: @Slaw to be clear, I said that I would sooner not give them the ability to use this method at all, rather than have a stream thhat might die because its upstream was closed early. Clearly your solution is better than a resource leak. But ultimately, it does not accomplish my goal providing a method that cannot be easiy abused. I will concede that Ishould have clarified that from the beginning.

Comment: @Slaw And as for whether or not your solution is sensible, of course it is sensible..... for a team that can follow basic directions and manage a simple resource. But the nature of my question should hint you towards the nature of my problem -- I am trying to avoid using a twr block. Which means, I am trying to avoid using one of the most basic resource acquisition features for fear that I might "forget it". Someone who is afraid of that is in a situation where even mild friction is too much. So, a solution that swaps one problem for another (albeit more consistent) problem doesn't help much.

Comment: @Slaw in order for a solution to meet my needs, it will need to maintain the existing semantics of a stream, while avoiding unpleasant surprises, like returning closed streams. So, for example, if returning a Stream at all were a compile time error, that would be an excellent exampleof something tat would more accurately meeet myneeds. Then we have a guard rail that a user would have to exhert significant eeffort to surpass. They wouldn't be able to get past it using Streams in ther most common form.

Comment: @Slaw And as you said, I expect that Basil's suggestion isprobably going to be the best that can be done. Which is fine if so. I'll open up a bounty to be sure though

Comment: Alas, anything I think of to give you the safety you want at compile-time involves hiding the stream from the caller. For fixed operations that's not really a problem, as Basil's idea is easy to implement. However, if you want the full flexibility of the stream API, you'll probably have to create some kind of "operation builder" API then have the execute-around method actually execute the stream based on the "built" operations and return the result. But not only is that a likely non-trivial up front development cost, you now have to maintain that API if and when the `Stream` interface changes.

Comment: @Slaw Now you're talking. You're basically saying that I have to bite the bullet once, stress test it to hell, and then come prepared to do it all over every time I upgrade my Java version? This sounds way better. I will give it a shot and come back to this question once I have completed that. However, that will likely become a Code Review post. Maybe I'll just post it into both. Regardless, this is extremely helpful, ty vm!

Comment: In fact, I will start off at Stackoverflow, perfect it to the best of my ability, then present it here for any bugs I come across. Once I iron out all the bugs I can, I will submit it as an answer to this post, and then I will send it for multiple rounds of Review at Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Slaw I'm digging around, don't tell me it is as simple as this, is it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37420279

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256837/discussion-between-davidalayachew-and-slaw).

Comment: Sorry mate I still don't get it. Consumers don't return anything. Where is the 'return' in this scheme that you're worrying about?

Comment: @user207421 Don't apologize. I am saying that I could replace a `Consumer` with a `Function`, switch my `accept` to an `apply`, store the result of `apply` in a value, then return the value instead of having the method be void. That works great, until the user returns the `Stream` itself, and it fails for the reasons I listed in my question. Lmk if those reasons don't make sense, and I can expand on them.

Comment: So don't make it a `Function` then. We seem to be just going around in circles.

Comment: @user207421 In my above code example, I have a method called `executeAroundMethodPattern`. It is currently `void`. That is fine, but that means that I can only perform `Stream` operations that do side-effects. But really, most `Stream` operations are transformations or reductions of the source data. Which means, I want my `executeAroundMethodPattern` to return something. For example, in my example above, I want to find the first 10 lines with a length >= 20. How would I do that?

Comment: @user207421 My first instinct on how would be to just switch my `Consumer` to a `Function`, and make `executeAroundMethodPattern` no longer be `void`. From there, I call the `apply` method from `Function`, and return its value. Now, by all means, if you can think of a way for me to get my transformation without doing the above, I am all ears. But it seemed like the most natural way to extract the value is to do what I just said.

Comment: I can. Leave it as `Consumer`, `void`, etc., *as you originally had it.* Everything beyond that is a difficulty of your own invention.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256843/discussion-between-davidalayachew-and-user207421).

Comment: For those who may be interested, I found a way around my dilemma (with help from various folks here). I have posted a code review request on stack exchange for my final implementation. Here is a link -- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/290912

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote:

> returning a value is easy enough, but I couldn't find a way to stop the user from just returning the `Stream` itself, nullifying the entire point of what I am trying to do here.

There is no other way to stop developers from returning the `Stream` than documenting that this won’t work. To show an example from the experts:

##### [`StackWalker.walk(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.html#walk(java.util.function.Function))

> ###### `public <T> T walk(Function<? super Stream<StackWalker.StackFrame>,? extends T> function)`
>
> Applies the given function to the stream of `StackFrame`s for the current thread, traversing from the top frame of the stack, which is the method calling this `walk` method.
>
> The `StackFrame` stream will be closed when this method returns. When a closed `Stream<StackFrame>` object is reused, `IllegalStateException` will be thrown.

So the JDK developers did not find an alternative to just documenting the restriction. But it seems, they do not share your opinion about “juniors”, to end up omitting a feature just because it could be used in the wrong way. Otherwise, since there is no “airtight” software in real life, you would end up with no software at all.

A solution that fails immediately on the first test when used incorrectly is not “nullifying the entire point” of your solution, as your original point was “*To avoid errors, I want to remove at least one particular tripping hazard -- the need for a try-with-resources*”. This goal is still achieved and it’s striking that your original idea explicitly mentioned removing **one** tripping hazard, not all of them.

Even with a `Consumer`, you can’t prevent callers from providing a consumer storing the `Stream` in a heap variable, to attempt to use it later, or forgetting the `filter` when using a non-short-circuiting terminal operation.

What will happen when you deny your “juniors” this method because it is not “airtight”? They will have to implement this functionality themselves, including those potential errors your method did already avoid. Like just doing the tempting one-liner `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())) .lines() .forEach(…)`

If you fear “that the reviewers are overburdened” with a problem that would be detected on the first test, you probably should change your processes, to perform unit tests first and only perform code review by humans if the code passed the automated tests.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, busy with work. Not to invalidate your entire answer, but I actually had the pleasure of reading through the work of the original Lambda teams effort back in the creation of Java 8, and long story short, not only was what I requested possible, but somewhere in their old Mercurial repository, there is a working implementation that handles resource management in the Stream. However, they decided that they did not want to burden all stream users for what is .1% of use cases.

Comment: All of that is to say, I believe your answer to be incorrect because I received evidence that comes straight from the horse's mouth that appears to contradict your answer ---- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28814024/10118965 --- and this one too --- https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-August/002195.html

Comment: That said, I think your overall point is probably correct. As is, I am trying solve a culture problem with code, and your answer basically boils down to "don't"which is fair. Still, now that I know that my original target is not only possible, but that it has already been done (and by the original Java developers to boot!), I hesitate to accept this as an answer, obviously putting aside the parts of it that are incorrect.

Comment: Hopefully you understand me at least partially though, yes? If what I am striving for is actually achievable, then I have code that takes way more effort to break in the way described. Obviously, like you said, someone could store a reference to the `Stream`. But you have to go out of your way to do that. Whereas, returning a `Stream` is not too unusual a thing to do.

Comment: I don’t see the contradiction in those links. They acknowledge that there is no other solution. So they thought about a specific feature a decade ago but dropped it. That’s as helpful as telling you that there would be an alternative solution in other programming languages. In the standard Java of 2024, there is no other solution.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. Work. Yes, I suppose that that is not very helpful. I only brought it up because the language made it imply that there was definitively no solution out there, and provably so. As opposed to, no one has deeemed it worth the effortto achieve whatI wish to. Either way, your point stands.

Comment: As a heads up, I am switching gears, and I am attempting to try implementing my own version of Stream that obviates the need for TWR at all, at least at callsite. Every terminal operation would delegate to an encapsulated stream, but it would do twr on the resources contained within my custom stream implementation.

Comment: Keep in mind that invocation of the terminal operation is not guaranteed. E.g. the result of `Files.lines()` should be closed, even if the caller never commences a terminal operation or an exception occurs before that. With your own version, it would be possible to be safe if you make the initial (backend) Stream creation lazy, to allocate and release the resource within the terminal operation only.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I will refactor my solution to do exactly that. I had originally considered doing it that way, but wasn't sure what the benefit would be for doing so. I can see that my fuzzy feeling was correct in the first place.

Comment: So, instead of storing a `Stream<T>`, I will instead store a `Function<Stream<T>, ???>`, then I can use the `Function.thenApply` to stack the changes, right? And then finally do what you say in the terminal operations.

Comment: A `Supplier<Stream<T>>` would be the right choice.

Comment: Hmmmm, ok. I was thinking since I have my `URI`, which is not yet a resource that needs to be handled, then I should be good without using a `Supplier`, right? And either way, don't I need to store all the stream intermediate operations somewhere? I would think function is perfect for this

Comment: Of course, that will work if you have a specific stream source. A `Supplier<Stream<T>>` (or `Callable<Stream<T>>` to support checked exceptions) would only be necessary if you want to have an abstraction for supporting arbitrary sources.

Comment: Perfect, then I have a very clear path forward. Huge help, ty vm!

Comment: Ok, I have completed my implementation. For those who would like to code review it on the Code Review Stack Exchange sister site, here is the link -- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/290912

Comment: @davidalayachew I only skimmed over the code but it looks like a typical delegation approach. So letting potential slips or typos aside, it looks like it should work. Note that since `Stream` is an interface, you could also use a [`Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) approach, to handle all delegation in a single method. You only have to prepare a map telling which methods are terminal operations.

Comment: Delegation and Proxy? Gang of Four! I'm a Junior Dev at my job (only recently promoted from intern), and they introduced me to the book. I know how to use Strategy and Visitor Pattern so far. Looks like I have 2 more to practice. Thank you again! I didn't know Java had a built in support for proxy

Comment: After attempting to create my own implementation, it has become more obvious that I am running into an XY problem. My ***REAL*** problem is that I don't have a clear or obvious way to detect a resource leak. So, in order to avoid having to detect it, I simply made it impossible to occur. However, in doing so, I introduced a whole slew of problems, and it's pretty clear that trying to solve those problems will introduce more. Instead, the real problem is resource leaks need to be detectable. In the code review post, I was made aware of tools that can detect resource leaks. Good enough I guess.

Comment: could you add that as an edit to your answer? I feel like that would be a good alternative to suggest to those who run into the same answer as me.