Java Open File handles for Directories
we realized by inspecting our java application that it seems to collect file handles. When we inspect with lsof what files are being held, they are all directories. We dont use WatchService or anything like that, but we do a bunch of file operations like reading, copying etc.
I am aware of Java try-with-resource for closing opened file streams, but here we talk all about directories. While searching the net, there seems to be no content about how to properly close or leaked directory file handles.
Interestingly we dont have such problems in our staging environment, but there is also less load.
What i know is, that the hardware and shares from which we are copying are quite unstable cifs shares. But the opened folder handles are all on our local disk...
Are you aware of any specific issues, how folder file handles can be leaking, or if there are any ways to protect against this if we know, that the underlying hardware may have problems?


Time to post, after much time creating, an MCVE.

Yea ... it depends on how you >are< dealing with the directories.

Directory walks, finds, Strams. Reading attributes, SMB. So specific load tests needed.

@RichieK your question boils down to 'does java have bugs where it randomly keeps dir handles around and how do you work around this bug'. This is a ... bit of a silly question; An SO answer of 'yes here is the bug report' is not really what it was meant for; it's not a 'help me search the web' kinda site. It's also highly unlikely; what's far more likely is that your software has the bug, not the JDK. But without code, we can't help. You might want to ask how one would go about asking the JVM where these open handles are coming from, but that's not what you are asking. Hence, vote-to-close.

@RichieK I do believe you need to pay attention to java.nio.file.Files#walk calls, javadoc says: "This method must be used within a try-with-resources statement or similar control structure to ensure that the stream's open directories are closed promptly after the stream's operations have completed."

After some heavy debugging, i figured out, that following code leaks to leak:
Files.list(parent).findAny().isEmpty

The documentation of Files.list says
The returned stream contains a reference to an open directory. The directory is closed by closing the stream.

I though the stream gets closed with a terminal operation, but that does not seem to be the case, at least with findAny.
Thanks to @Andrey pointing me to Files.walk

"I thought the stream gets closed with a terminal operation" - for why it doesn't, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813637/
